# How to plot normal distribution along a line?

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I am working on matlab code to plot normal distribution samples along a line. 
Keeping things simple for this question, I am using the line `y=10`.

```
A=randn(300,2);
x=A(:,1)';
y=A(:,2)';
x=[1.5*x(1:100)+5 1.5*x(101:200)+10 1.5*x(201:300)+15];
y=[1.5*y(1:100)+10 1.5*y(101:200)+10 1.5*y(201:300)+10];
plot(x,y,'Marker','.','LineStyle','none')
axis ( [ 1 20 1 20 ] ) ;
```

The aim is this:

[image: Normal Distribution Along a Line]

My problem is, this code seems to be very inefficient, especially these two lines:

```
x=[1.5*x(1:100)+5 1.5*x(101:200)+10 1.5*x(201:300)+15];
y=[1.5*y(1:100)+10 1.5*y(101:200)+10 1.5*y(201:300)+10];
```

In my actual code however, this will be expanded to something like

```
x=[1.5*x(1:100)+5 1.5*x(101:200)+10 1.5*x(201:300)+15 1.5*x(301:400)+20 1.5*x(401:500)+25 ................];
```

Is there a way I can make this more efficient, by using loops or vectorization? I am trying to understand how to do that, but I am only able to find simple examples. I can't understand how to iterate with two variables, one in the range part `x(201:300)....x(301:400)` and one in the addition part `+15...+20`

Also, is this technique I am using to plot normal distribution samples along a line the right technique, or is there a better / simpler method?

Comment: Why do you think those lines are inefficient? It's a vectorized code with small ranges, so it should be super fast.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: This is just an example code, in my actual code, the range might run into much more than thousands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done with [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html): align each type of variation in a different dimension, and let singleton expansion compute all "combinations":

```
A = randn(300,2);
offsets_x = [5 10 15]; % Or offsets_x = (1:size(A,1)/chunk_size)*5
offsets_y = [10 10 10];
chunk_size = 100;
x = bsxfun(@plus, 1.5*reshape(A(:,1), chunk_size, []), offsets_x);
y = bsxfun(@plus, 1.5*reshape(A(:,2), chunk_size, []), offsets_y);
x = x(:).';
y = y(:).';
```

From Matlab R2016 onwards, thanks to [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) you can replace the `bsxfun` lines by the simpler

```
x = 1.5*reshape(A(:,1), chunk_size, []) +  offsets_x;
y = 1.5*reshape(A(:,2), chunk_size, []) +  offsets_y;
```

Comment: Thanks! But it gives me errors of matrix dimension mismatch in both ways.

Comment: Not to me. No idea what the problem can be. I just edited to add the `A = ` line. Can you do `clear` and then paste my code as is?

Comment: It's working now. Is there a way `offsets_x = [5 10 15];` this can be automated instead of hard-coded? That was the problem I was facing in my original question, that in actual code I would have to write `offset_x=[5 10 15 20 25 30...]`

Comment: Well, you could always write something like `offset_x = (1:size(A,1)/chunk_size)*5`. Edited. I think that's more or less what the other answer does

Answer (score 2):

You are building x and y by multiplying A by a constant value (1.5), then splitting it in several parts (1:100, 101:200, 201:300...) and applying different offsets to each range.

You can do this directly to A. I splitted it in two lines for readability but you can do it in a single line.

```
% Build offsets:
n = 10;                 % number of parts with 100 samples each
step = 5;               % offset step: 5 -> 5, 10, 15, ... 
Offset = ones(100,n);  
Offset = bsxfun(@times,step:step:step*n,Offset);
Offset = Offset(:);

% Multiply by 1.5
A = 1.5 * randn(n*100,2);  

% Add offset to both X and Y
%A = bsxfun(@plus,A,Offset); 

% or add offset only to X and leave Y without offset:
A(:,1) = A(:,1) + Offset;


plot(A(:,1), A(:,2), 'Marker', '.', 'LineStyle', 'none')
%axis ([ 1 20 1 20 ]) ;
```

Result applying Offsets to both X and Y
[image: Result applying Offsets to both X and Y]

Comment: Thanks, but it is giving me error `Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in testtest (line 45)
A = bsxfun(@plus,Offset,A);`

Comment: Thanks! I have one more doubt, what if I want to have different offsets, like in my original question I had `y=x`, so I needed x-offset as 5 or 10, and y-offset as 0. How would I do that?

Comment: Thanks! I am just figuring out how to do the opposite diagonal. I tried adding offset to x, and subtracting from y, but to no avail!

Comment: `A(:,1) = A(:,1) + Offset; A(:,2) = A(:,2) - Offset;`